# Шорткод и get_term_link()

Tags: wordpress, шорткод

Пытаюсь реализовать такую штуку:

```html
add_shortcode('catlink', 'catlink_function');

function catlink_function($atts){
     extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     "num" => '',
     ), $atts));
return get_term_link( $num ,"product_cat");
}
```

Собственно, шорткод: [catlink num="1058"]

Выдает ошибку:

```html
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in www/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 345
```

Comment: вместо строки приходит объект типа `WP_Error`, видимо падает ошибка. Вам нужно в файле *shortcodes.php* смотреть строку 345. Больше нечего сказать по Вашему вопросу.

Comment: get_term_link() возвращает WP_Error, если такой таксономии не существует. Нет у вас такой таксономии с ID = 1058.

Comment: Такая таксономия у меня есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$num должен быть числом, иначе функция будет интерпретировать его как имя (slug). Вставьте (int) в код. Так работает, я проверил.

```
function catlink_function($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "num" => '',
    ), $atts));
    return get_term_link( (int) $num ,"product_cat");
}
add_shortcode('catlink', 'catlink_function');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает.